# how do i output an xml file using rest

Tags: java, xml, rest, output

i have an xml file called articles.xml that i am trying to access with a rest service.
what i want to do is get all the articles in the articles.xml file and display them using a rest service.

i have a java class called RestArticleFilter.java which is where i am trying to produce the code for this.

my main problem is that i don't understand how to access the xml file in eclipse
is something like this getting close to what i need to do?

```
public void getArticles()
{
       for (Article article : "articles.xml")
       {//System.out.println(article)}
}
```

not sure if it helps, but im using jersey.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of the file as a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) (Java 7) object then read the file and parse it to your type.

Something like:

```
 File file = new File("src/main/resources/articles.xml");
 String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
 Article article = parseTheFile(contents);
```